# How to get value from dropdown list with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I populated a select box with data from the backend and it works well, but when I click on an item to get its value, it gives me undefined:

```html
<div class="col-md-5">
  <label class="child-label" for="existing-phases">Existing:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="MyData">
    <option disabled selected value>-- select an option --</option>
    <option ng-repeat="var in payloadSecteur" value="{{var.id}}">{{ var.secteur }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <a class="btn btn-primary add-contract-button pull-right" ng-click="showPopup()">+</a>
</div>
```

Here's the function:

```
$scope.showPopup=function(){
  alert('eee');
  alert($scope.MyData);
};
```

Comment: thank u for ur answer...i cant get the value when click it

Comment: Please show add an example of what `payloadSecteur` looks like to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working snippet of your code without the value attribute set in the option tag and the options have been hard coded ,it is working perfectly

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <label class="child-label" for="existing-phases">Existing:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="MyData">
    <option disabled selected value>-- select an option --</option>
    <option>heldfd</option>
    <option>asdf</option>
    <option>asdf</option>
    <option>asdf</option>
  </select>
  <a class="btn btn-primary add-contract-button pull-right" ng-click="showPopup()">+</a>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.showPopup=function(){
  alert($scope.MyData);
};
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you have a url where you have deployed the code ?

Comment: did you try removing the value attribute in the option tags and trying?and what value are you getting for this part "alert($scope.MyData);" in your local are you getting undefined or null or something like that?

Comment: i got undefined

Comment: can u send me a like to pass on chat??

Comment: i don't have the access to do that i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129340/discussion-between-graveyardqueen-and-imsi-imsi).

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your html code to div with ng-app and ng-controller defined and defined them in your Angular file? Remember also to write your Angular function into the controller.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <p>Select a car:</p>

  <select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x for (x, y) in cars">
  </select>

  <h1>You selected: {{selectedCar}}</h1>

</div>
```

Angular:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = {
        car01 : "Ford",
        car02 : "Fiat",
        car03 : "Volvo"
    }
});
</script>
```

Remember also, that you don't have to use `<option>` tag - `<select>` with `ng-options` will be enough.

Comment: thank you ser...you should know ..that i got the data from my backend thats mean it works well..my problem is when clicked on an item on the select box i cant get its value

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <div class="col-md-5">

        <label class="child-label" for="existing-phases">Existing:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>

        <select class="form-control" ng-model="MyData" ng-options="payloadSecteur for payloadSecteur in payloadSecteur"></select>

        <a class="btn btn-primary add-contract-button pull-right" ng-click="showPopup()">+</a>

    </div>

</div>
```

---

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {


  $scope.payloadSecteur = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

  $scope.showPopup = function() {
    console.log('eee');
    console.log($scope.MyData);
  };

}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5dv970b/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
Pass ng-model as a parameter in showPopup() like

```
ng-click="showPopup(MyData)"
```

In controller

```
$scope.showPopup=function(selectedData){
alert('eee');
alert(selectedData);
};
```